# How to set default values when destructing an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript, to destruct multiple props, how do I set prop1, prop2, prop3 with default value individually?

```
const {
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3
  } = obj.props;
```

Comment: Try `const { prop1 = 'default1' } = obj.props`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would set default values in function params, with an `=` sign.

```
const {
  prop1 = 'default value',
  prop2,
  prop3,
} = obj.props;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values